# Need some help in accessing an xml document to add/remove content

Tags: php, xml

I am working with an XML document with the structure shown below and i am trying to add/remove image objects without having to treat the xml document as text. Each image object corresponds to a picture in the album.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gallery galleryTitle="Photo Album">
  <image imageURL="../Photoalbum/artwork/eb98e388e14b11008d4ffb595b9ed3e6.jpg"
    thumbURL="../Photoalbum/artwork/thumbs/tn_eb98e388e14b11008d4ffb595b9ed3e6.jpg"
    linkURL="../Photoalbum/artwork/eb98e388e14b11008d4ffb595b9ed3e6.jpg" 
    linkTarget="_blank">    
    <title>A Title</title>
    <caption>A caption</caption>    
  </image> 
</gallery>
```

I have been able to access and print the xml file as a whole with the code below

```
if (file_exists('file.xml')) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('file.xml'); 
    print"<pre>";
    print_r($xml);
}
```

but so far have not been able to access individual fields of the image object. The object that will be added/removed will be identified by a unique filename such as eb98e388e14b11008d4ffb595b9ed3e6.jpg so once this filename is found in the XML document, i want the whole image object removed. Similarly, i would like to be able to add a new image object with a new filename.

Let me know if my question is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `xpath()` to select the `<image>`-node. `xpath` is like SQL for XML:

```
$image = $xml->xpath("/gallery/image[contains(@imageURL, $filename)]");
```

... and `unset()` to remove that node:

```
if (isset($image[0])) unset($image[0][0]);
```

see it working: https://eval.in/135145

use the search-function to see how to add a new `<image>` with `SimpleXml`.

Comment: This works. Thanks, much simpler than what i was trying